# time specific actionListener in java

Tags: java, awt, actionlistener

I want to write a time specific actionListener which triggers some action at a specific time. I know that there is ScheduledExecutorService in java which can be used to trigger a action at some specific time but I want to try actionListener.

Let suppose I create a txt file and want to remove it after an hour. How can I do it by actionListener ? any example code ?

Comment: An ActionListener *responds* to an action - you want to *perform* an action at some later point in time... ActionListener doesn't have anything directly to do with this (other than perhaps kicking off the process if you're doing it via a button press)

Comment: exactly ActionListener responds to an action. Triggering a specific time could also be an action. I am not using any swing or awt component like buttons or anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to write a time specific actionListener which triggers some
>   action at a specific time. I know that there is
>   ScheduledExecutorService in java which can be used to trigger a action
>   at some specific time but I want to try actionListener.

have look at `Swing Timer` and event from timer should be invoke `Swing Action`/`ActionListener`,

> Let suppose I create a txt file and want to remove it after an hour.
>   How can I do it by actionListener ? any example code ?

read Oracles Tutorials for working code examples in MCVE/SSCCE form,

How to use -

- [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)
- [Swing Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) / [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Comment: I dont think I need to look for Swing Actions or Swing Timer because I am not using any Swing component. I just want to trigger an action at a specific time (1 hour after file creation).

Comment: @JavaDeveloper as Nate told you in his comment, `ActionListener` responds to an Action (i.e. pressing a button, clicking on a checkbox, combo box, etc). And as I have read on your comment to Nate too, well `actionListeners` are made for `swing`, then you don't want an `actionListener`. Please if you want a better help explain in simple word what you want and provide an example (if posible)

Comment: Ok, if ActionListeners are specific for awt components then perhaps I am not going to use it. Its better to use ScheduledExecutorService. Thanks for help and explanation.

Comment: not ActionListeners is packaged in awt tree in Java, isn't specifics for AWT Components